# Need help setting a texture background to a container div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to set a texture background to a container div. My CSS is below:

```
.container {
  background-image: url(..img/texture-one.png) repeat;
}
```

My problem is, the image isn't showing up. If I make an `img` tag in my HTML, the image shows up using the same path.

Comment: Don't you mean ../image instead of ..image? Plus, if you do this the container won't auto-size based on the image, so make sure to add height/width attributes or something.

Comment: Make sure that the url is relative to the css file (or html file) that has your .container declared.

Answer (score 1):

```
.container {
    background-image: url("img/texture-one.png");
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**background-image** can have only image path.

`background-image: url|none|initial|inherit;`

**background** is shorthand for multiple background properties.

`background: bg-color bg-image position/bg-size bg-repeat bg-origin bg-clip bg-attachment initial|inherit;`

So you need:

```
.container {
   background: url(..img/texture-one.png) repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps just add quotes around image link?

```
.container {
  background-image: url("img/texture-one.png");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you show the HTML code too?

If you have floated elements inside the container, then the height of the container is 0, so you can't see a thing. In this case, you should use `overflow: auto;` on the container.